# Electromotive force is a potential difference or it is an energy?

Tags: electromagnetism, potential, voltage, definition

[Electromotive force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromotive_force) is a potential difference or it is an energy?

Answer (score 2):

Emf and potential difference each have the units $\text{J C}^{-1}$, so each could be called an 'energy per coulomb'. They are not, though, the same thing...

Potential difference between two points is the difference in electrical potential energy per unit 'test' charge when a small test charge goes from one point to the other.

The difference in electrical potential energy arises because of a static (or quasi-static) distribution of charges in the vicinity. For example, there is a pd between the terminals of a battery, because there are equal and opposite charges on its terminals.

Emf is also an energy (difference) per coulomb. It arises from forces other than electrostatic ones. For example it might arise from the electric field which curls around the changing magnetic field when we plunge a magnet into a coil. The emf is the work done by this electric field on a 'test' charge flowing through the coil when the coil is part of a complete circuit. The emf in the coil, or in a battery, is what causes the charges on the terminals (see last paragraph) even if nothing is connected to the coil or battery. Unlike pd, the emf depends on the route along which the test charge goes from one point to another.

There are several difficult ideas in this answer, and you're likely to need plenty of examples and practice in order to grasp them. It will take time. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

An electromotive force due to a varying magnetic flux through a conducting loop causes the movement of charges in the loop. When the loop is open, this leads to the pile up of negative and positive charges at the ends of the conducting loop. This produces an (electrostatic) potential difference between the ends of the loop. The same happens at the terminals of an electric generator which have a dc or ac electric potential difference (voltage).